# My node js program is giving me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined", when reading a json file

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to read frpm a json file folder withing my program and i want to use a GET list endpoint to read through browser or postman, but i'm getting the above TypeError. Here is my code:

model.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');

  function loadTeams() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('./json/prov-nodes.json', (err, data) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          const teams = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(teams);
          resolve(teams);
      });
    });
}
```

app.use(bodyParser.json());

```
app.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    let teams = [];
    loadTeams()
      .then(function(data){   
        teams = JSON.stringify(data); 
        console.log(teams);  
        **res.send(teams);** //intended to send to browser/postman response
        console.log('try...part ..read call');

      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      res.send("My root page");
      console.log(teams);
     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `loadTeams` function does not return a promise, and therefore you cannot call `.then()`.

You can wrap the function in a promise like this:

```js
function loadTeams() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile('./json/prov-nodes.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            try {
                const teams = JSON.parse(data);
                return resolve(teams);
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I changed as you suggested, but gott following Error:        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: I don't see Route.post in the code you provided. Can you add that code to the original post?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `loadTeams` as an async function you should turn it into a function that returns `Promise` with a callback results:

```js
function loadTeams() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./json/prov-nodes.json', (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        const teams = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(teams);
        resolve(teams);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your promt reply. Your code reacts to "=>", and when removed, it expects a ";". Then the code in the block "fs.readFile" is not highlighted.

Comment: Ichanged the codes you provided and ajusted a litlle, but now, it runs okey and returning the list in the terminal, but fails on the browser and postman. now it returns error and display "Not my root page" like in the code below:

app.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    let teams = [];
    loadTeams()
      .then(function(data){   
        teams = data; 
        console.log(teams);  
        res.send(teams);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      res.send("My root page");
      console.log(teams);
     
});

Comment: And can you update your post with the most recent code?

Comment: Your updated code now works, but the problem now is that i get the response in the visual studio code terminal. GET in postman or browser like "127.0.0.1:3000/list" returns nothing.

Comment: Add console.log before ` res.send(data);` to look at `data`

Comment: Yeah, i did earlier, but the it's displayed on the VSC terminal, and not on postman response, or browser. Check the updated code above.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: i'm back after xmas break. Probably do not need JSON.stringify. Just removed it, but my problem as i mentioned is that i get a json response at the visual studio code terminal, but when testing i postman, i neither get a response nor an error.

Comment: Did you try `res.json(data)`?

Comment: Yes i did @Anatoly, but i still get response in the visual studio code terminal. POSTMAN when i run the GET -Request returns 1 and status code 200 OK. but not the json file.

Comment: Try to use some other REST client like Insomnia