# My Node js program gives me an error "my add function is not a function"

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm still new to Node js and i'm bulding a MVC program that POST a json object in POSTMAN. But my add-function **(addera())** in the model.js should sum up the values in the json object. When applied through the controller, the function is rejected as not a function. What could be the problem? My app executes from web-app.js---->apiRoutes.js---controller.js----model.js. Hereis my code.

web-app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const apiRoute  = require('./apiServer/routes/apiRoutes');
const app = express();

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3001

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/math', apiRoute);    // POSTMAN - POST- Request: { "tal": "10,343,24,345,22,23,233,45" }

app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

apiRoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const apiController = require('../controllers/apiController');
        
const router = express.Router();
        
router.post('/add', apiController.calculateSum);
    
module.exports = router;
```

apiController.js:

```
const mathServerModel = require("../../mathServer/model/mathModel");
const calculateSum = (req, res) => {
    mathServerModel.**addera**(req.body.tal)
    .then(function (data) {
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

module.exports = {
     calculateSum
}
```

mathsModel.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


  function addera(tal) {
    let strNumbersArr = tal.split(","); // ["10", "343", "24", ..., "233"]
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < strNumbersArr.length; i++) {
        let currentNumberStr = strNumbersArr[i];
    sum += Number(currentNumberStr); // convert current number string into a number
    }
    return sum;
}

/*
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let sum = addera(req.body.tal);  
    console.log(sum);
});*/

module.exports = {
    addera
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your mathsModel.js file, you must export an arrow function to be able to call that function in another file:

```
//mathsModel.js
const addera = async (tal) => {
    let strNumbersArr = tal.split(","); // ["10", "343", "24", ..., "233"]
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < strNumbersArr.length; i++) {
        let currentNumberStr = strNumbersArr[i];
        sum += Number(currentNumberStr); // convert current number string into a number
    }
    return sum;
}

module.exports = addera
```

You're calling `.then()` after the `addera()` call on apiController.js, that means you're handling a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), so your addera function must be an asynchronous function, that's why I added `async` on the function.

2. In apiController.js, you can't call  `mathServerModel.addera()` because you're requiring only the `addera()` function, not the whole file (I don't know why you added **), also, on `res.send(data)`, if you send an integer with `res.send()`, express will handle the number as a [http status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), you can convert the respose to an object with `res.send( {data} )`:

```
//apiController.js
const addera = require("../../mathServer/model/mathsModel");
const calculateSum = (req, res) => {
    addera(req.body.tal)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        res.send({data});
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

module.exports = {
    calculateSum
}
```

The code above should work as intended

Comment: Thank you so much @Gabriel Lobo. It worked fine as expected, and i've learned something from you. Cheers!

Comment: Kindly check this out if you can help.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423837/14551704